# Rerfering current bean in Spring using SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

How can i get the reference of the current bean in SpEL in xml configuration.
My code is something like this

{
`<bean id="circle" class="com.sample.beans.CircleType">
        <property name="radius" value="35.0"></property>
        <property name="perimeter" value="#{2*T(java.lang.Math).PI*circle.radius}" />
        <property name="area" value="#{T(java.lang.Math).PI*circle.radius^2}" />
    </bean>`
}

I want to refer property radius while evaluating perimeter and area. How to do this.
any catch ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should just put the value of radius inside perimeter and area

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because the bean is in the process of being instantiated when the expression is evaluated.